# Is there any python package which essentially converts the presented HTML structure into JSON/YAML format

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

For Example there is a code present in HTML

```
<p>Example of a paragraph element.</p> 
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

needs to represented into (in case of a yaml format) or json is also fine

```
p: Example of a paragraph element.
ul:
   li:Coffee
   li:Tea
   li:Milk
```

Comment: I doubt there's a readymade package for it. This can be done with a bit of recursion, but what have you tried already? And why do you need this, if I may ask?

Comment: Thanks @slhck , was able to extend more with beautifulsoup and solved it the way given below. Thanks so much for your response

Comment: The answer does not achieve the indentation that you were looking for, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there is a package, but you could just iterate through each tag in the html, then use `.name` and `.text` to work it out hat way, and write to file:

```
html = '''<p>Example of a paragraph element.</p> 
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all():
    print (tag.name + ':' + tag.text)
```

**Output:**

```
p:Example of a paragraph element.
ul:
Coffee
Tea
Milk

li:Coffee
li:Tea
li:Milk
```

Comment: Oh Wow, thats an awesome way, I did not knew about it, Thanks a ton for your time @chitown88

Comment: Looks like i need to learn more on Beautiful soup extractions, Do you have any good reference to look at, the original documentation is too bulky

Comment: Oh man. I know what you mean. I've had a hard time with the documentation as well. The best way that I've learned was literally from SO. I'll answer questions (like this), and then sometimes others will have a better solution, and I just learn from seeing the different ways people answer the question. Either that, or just trial and error and try to work it out. I'm always learning something new from the users on here.

Comment: as far as references, I liked [this book](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/4622595946005004561?q=web+scraping+o+neil&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS822US822&biw=1366&bih=635&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX1sxze4XGLf26fggFcX_glF5TXXLl8Xfdb_X8DWwu4SKq_Y4aiTsxQPv5PtGSgV4d41wUYUvRSJdOqDR0v-YL39SkCKp66zl5vn0MRw6JmvJxayijRIZAFPVH72wEFfkRfzHjxtKSNOrZYFGNiVeyw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRlYqI5u3hAhUJKKwKHXW5CQQQ8wIIqAE)

Comment: and [this one](https://www.kobo.com/gb/en/ebook/web-scraping-with-python-1?utm_campaign=shopping_feed_gb_en&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2IrmBRCJARIsAJZDdxDwreK30eMlluzMsTfdDaN5d0rJs8vmyNNMBingm1P5peZrkFWf52gaAr8tEALw_wcB). There are probably other good ones out there too, but these were the ones I was able to get from my University library